# Command line argument validation library for Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am looking for a reusable code snippet that does command line argument validation for bash.

Ideally something akin to the functionality offered by Apache Commons CLI:

Commons CLI supports different types of options:

- POSIX like options (ie. tar -zxvf foo.tar.gz)
- GNU like long options (ie. du --human-readable --max-depth=1)
- Short options with value attached (ie. gcc -O2 foo.c)
- long options with single hyphen (ie. ant -projecthelp)
- ...

and it generates a "usage" message for the program automatically, like this:

```
usage: ls
 -A,--almost-all          do not list implied . and ..
 -a,--all                 do not hide entries starting with .
 -B,--ignore-backups      do not list implied entried ending with ~
 -b,--escape              print octal escapes for nongraphic characters
    --block-size <SIZE>   use SIZE-byte blocks
 -c                       with -lt: sort by, and show, ctime (time of last
                          modification of file status information) with
                          -l:show ctime and sort by name otherwise: sort
                          by ctime
 -C                       list entries by columns
```

I would include this code snippet at the beginning of my Bash scripts and reuse it across scripts.

There must be something like this. I don't believe we are all writing code to this effect or similar:

```
#!/bin/bash

NUMBER_OF_REQUIRED_COMMAND_LINE_ARGUMENTS=3

number_of_supplied_command_line_arguments=$#

function show_command_usage() {
  echo usage:
  (...)
}

if (( number_of_supplied_command_line_arguments < NUMBER_OF_REQUIRED_COMMAND_LINE_ARGUMENTS )); then
  show_command_usage
  exit
fi

...
```

Comment: Use `getopts` for short options. See [BashFAQ/35](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035). Write your script in Python and use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html).

Comment: I suspect the answer is that the lack of a module infrastructure makes loading a source library in a portable way roughly the same amount of effort as rewriting the option parsing every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the solution I use (found it on the net somewhere, probably here itself, don't remember for sure). Please note that the GNU getopt (`/usr/bin/getopt`) does support single dash long options (`ant -projecthelp` style) using the option `-a`, however I haven't used it so it is not shown in the example.

This code parses for 3 options: `--host value` or `-h value`, `--port value` or `-p value` and `--table value` or `-t value`. In case the required parameter isn't set, a test for it is

```
# Get and parse options using /usr/bin/getopt
OPTIONS=$(getopt -o h:p:t: --long host:,port:,table: -n "$0" -- "$@")
# Note the quotes around `$OPTIONS': they are essential for handling spaces in 
# option values!
eval set -- "$OPTIONS"

while true ; do
    case "$1" in
            -h|--host) HOST=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
            -t|--table)TABLE=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
            -p|--port)
                    case "$2" in
                            "") PORT=1313; shift 2 ;;
                            *)  PORT=$2; shift 2 ;;
                    esac;;
            --) shift ; break ;;
            *) echo "Internal error!" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
if [[ -z "$HOST" ]] || [[-z "$TABLE" ]] || [[ -z "$PORT" ]] ; then
    usage()
    exit
if
```

An alternative implementation using the `getopts` shell builtin(this only supports small options):

```
while getopts ":h:p:t:" option; do
    case "$option" in
         h) HOST=$OPTARG ;;
         p) PORT=$OPTARG ;;
         t) TABLE=$OPTARG ;;
        *) usage(); exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
if [[ -z "$HOST" ]] || [[-z "$TABLE" ]] || [[ -z "$PORT" ]] ; then
    usage()
    exit
if

shift $((OPTIND - 1))
```

Further reading for [GNU getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) and [getopts bash builtin](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)