# Checking arguments in terminal

Tags: c++, linux

How can I write a program to check the arguments in the terminal are correct?

For example, if I have a program `hello.cpp` and I want to call it as:

```
./hello yes 10
```

I want the program to make sure that the first argument is yes or no and the second argument is a number between 1-10.  So how can I read these arguments into my program to do the checking?

Thanks!

Comment: any reason as to why you cannot do this inside the program?

Comment: How can I handle the arguments in the program? @Rohan, c++

Comment: One doesn't run .cpp files like that.

Comment: In C++, you would get `char *argv[]` to your `main()` in which you can check.

Comment: @BobJohn you might want to take a look at this as well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220715/command-line-argument-validation-library-for-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command line arguments are passed as a count and individual strings in the `argc` and `argv` arguments to `main()`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   ...
}
```

Simply check the value in `argc` and the strings in `argv` for the appropriate values.

Answer (score 3):

You meant to execute like this, ./hello yes 10

there is an option argc and argv in c
where argc is the number of arguments passed and argv with the index shows the argument passed itself.

Take a look at the below code for iterating through all arguments.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other users, The `main` function is the [entry point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function) of your program, and the way it gets data from the command line is through its parameters.

The first `int` argument is the count of all the arguments passed, including the program name, the second `char **` argument is a pointer to each parameter passed, including the program name:

```
int main
(
    int argc,       // <-- how many parameters has been provided? 
    char **argv,    // <-- what values has each parameter?
)
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

So, knowing that, your call `./hello yes 10` must be like that:

```
argc = 3
argv[0] = "./hello"
argv[1] = "yes"
argv[2] = "10"
```

The names `argc` and `argv` are just a convention, you can name them at your pleasure, but it's a good practice to keep the names that everyone are used for.

And the argument doesn't are forced to be `int, char **` they must follow a quite rigid convention, borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1621664/499359):

> It shall have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall allow both the following definitions of main: int main() and int main(int argc, char* argv[])

Knowing that, let's focus on your question:

First of all, you must ensure that 2 arguments are passed, so you must check the `argc` value and ensure that equals exactly `3`.

> the first argument is yes or no

Next, you must store your `argv[1]` (because `0` contains the program name) into a string and compare it with the values `"yes"` and `"no"`:

```
    std::string YesOrNo(argv[1]);
    if (YesOrNo == "yes" || YesOrNo == "no")
```

And finally, you must store your `argv[2]` into an integer and check if it is equal or less to `10`:

```
    std::stringstream Stream;
    int Value = 0;
    Stream << argv[2];
    Stream >> Value;

    if (Value <= 10)
```

So, the result is:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        std::string YesOrNo(argv[1]);

        if (YesOrNo == "yes" || YesOrNo == "no")
        {
            std::stringstream Stream;
            int Value = 0;
            Stream << argv[2];
            Stream >> Value;

            if (Value <= 10)
            {
                // Your stuff..
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I let you deal with all the uppercase and lowercase stuff and the false positives with the numeric argument, at least I'm not going to do *all* your homework ;)